# setState in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and I can't seem to find out why the result of the following setState is not as I expect it to be (i.e. to increment the value every second by 1)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Layout extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: "Behnam",
            i: 0
        }
    }

    render() {

        setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({ name : "Behnam" + this.state.i });
            this.setState({ i: this.state.i + 1 });
        }, 1000);

        return (
            <div className="container">
                {this.state.name}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Instead the output string rapidly increases (I guess as fast as react is trying to keep its' virtual DOM updated). So I was wondering what is the right way to do this?

Comment: You have done it in the wrong way. Know that setState will trigger the render method, so in your code you have done some kind of loop of render > setState > render > setState.... The good way is put the setInterval inside componentDidMount method of react component lifecycle (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html), so your render will be only declarative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you change the state, you rerender the component.
Because you initiated the `setInterval` in the render method, you get another interval, which changes the state, and rerenders, and so on.

Move the `setInterval` to [componentDidMount](http://componentDidMount), which is invoked only once, when the component mounts:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Layout extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: "Behnam",
            i: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() { set the interval after the component mounted, and save the reference
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({ 
                name: `Behnam${this.state.i}`, 
                i: this.state.i + 1
            });
        }, 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval); // clear the interval when the component unmounts
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {this.state.name}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is creating an interval *every* time the component is rendered, so there are multiple timers incrementing the value. You probably want to do it in `componentDidMount()` instead of `render()`. See [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount).

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Layout extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            name: "Behnam",
            i: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({ name : "Behnam" + this.state.i });
            this.setState({ i: this.state.i + 1 });
        }, 1000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {this.state.name}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Layout />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time a render is triggered, you're calling `setInterval` again, adding to the number of active intervals on the page.

You should perhaps make use of another lifecycle method, such as `componentDidMount`. You should remember to save the interval ID returned by `setInterval`, so that you can call `clearInterval` in `componentWillUnmount`.